# Wordpress : how to allow PHP in tag or category description?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, categories, field-description

(Sorry for my bad english, I'm french)

I would like to add PHP code in category/tags description field (Wordpress).
What can I add in my functions.php file ?

In fact, I would like to run shortcodes inside this field. So I put this code in my functions.php :

```
add_filter( 'term_description', 'shortcode_unautop' );
add_filter( 'term_description', 'do_shortcode' );
remove_filter( 'pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );
remove_filter( 'term_description', 'wp_kses_data' );
```

It works with some shortcodes, but not all. So I would like to try this :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[myshortcode]'); ?>
```

But PHP can't run in description field of category and tag pages.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What have you tried? And maybe an example of current output and desired output?

Comment: Allowing executable php-code generated by users (even when they are admins or moderators...) is not a good idea. What are you trying to achieve? Because, there are probably multiple solutions to your problem without this security risk.

Comment: I just want to allow for me, not for other people. In fact, I want to run PHP in this field. I change the word "allow" in my question and add more details about what I would like to do.

Comment: I don't see a point of having PHP in the fields in your admin panel, just write it in the files that you want this to show up. I advice you keep all fields with only text, and sometimes HTML if you need, but having actual code in them is a bad idea.

Comment: @CritingZ The interest is to be able to run shortcodes as explained. At first even the HTML was not allowed in these fields, but I had found how to make it so. My category and tag pages are a lot of traffic and I would like to display, before the posts list, a selection of products which are managed by a plugin. That's the interest and my wish to run a shortcode (via php because it does not work otherwise).

Comment: I see. You can add custom fields to categories and tags via the Wordpress API, if the field is editor, in it you can copy/paste the shortcode and it will work.

Comment: Even if the field is a text only, when you put a shorcode, in the backend you can do do_shortdode('the_custom_field');

Comment: @CritingZ Good idea ! But custom fields are only for pages / posts, not for category / tags pages. I will try to find a plugin to add them. Unless you have a solution for that? thank you so much

Comment: I installed the "Advanced Custom Fields" extension to have custom fields in the tags / categories pages ... but the shortcode to display the contents of these do not work (some shortcodes work in the description field, others no). Another solution would be to modify the code I added in functions.php (see my question) so that all shortcodes work no? Which would prevent me from trying to display PHP via custom fields.

Comment: @triphop you can have custom fields everywhere, on categories, tags, everywhere. You can use framework to add them, it's really easy, there are Redux Framework, Options Framework and etc. it's literally 10 lines of code to add a custom field to categories and etc. I hope that helps, for me, it's the best option.

Comment: Why some shortcodes work and some don't? I think if one works, all of them should, maybe there is a problem with the shortcode itself then.

Comment: @CritingZ Yes I think it's the best solution thanks again. I do not know why some shortcodes do not work and others yes. You might think it's my extension "AAWP" that does not work but the shortcode of "Advanced Custom Fields" did not work either ... I contacted AAWP support to find out why their shortcode does not work . If they find a solution it will be another way to solve the problem, because in thinking it is the only one that I intend to use in the description field. Good day to you !

Comment: Have you tried using an Iframe plugin?
Could add to the block.

Or to be more practical you could install a plugin to edit each category page.

I hope you got it right. Not for your English, but where exactly you want to expose this php.